# Script to get the storage value of AMQ

Tags: linux, shell-script

Script that I made.

```
#!/bin/bash

amqBaseURL="http://10.199.199.199:8080"

/usr/bin/wget --http-user=admin --http-password=admin $amqBaseURL/admin/ -O amq1.html

store=`cat amq1.html |sed -n '/Store/{n;p}'|grep -o "[0-9]*"`

echo -e "$store"
```

Script output

```
--2019-01-23 21:25:13--  http://10.199.199.199:8080/admin/
Connecting to 10.199.199.199:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Unauthorized
Reusing existing connection to 10.199.199.199:8080.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7363 (7.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: â€œamq1.htmlâ€‌

100%[==========================================================================================================>] 7,363       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2019-01-23 21:25:13 (251 MB/s) - â€œamq1.htmlâ€‌ saved [7363/7363]

0
```

I need to get the output only the value. Instead of the whole length like everytime i run the script the output would only be.

```
100
```

I am running an external scheduler (Zabbix) for this script and the tool only accepts digits.

Comment: Have you looked into `wget --quiet`?

Comment: Thank you, got it. Just added -q between this line. 

/usr/bin/wget -q --http-user=admin

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer so that question can be marked closed. Credit to [DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20246/dopeghoti).
In order to suppress the full wget session output, the command can be run with the `-q` or `--quiet` flag. From the documentation:

> ```
>    -q
>    --quiet
>        Turn off Wget's output.
> ```

Alternatively, to get minimal output (e.g. errors) use the `-nv` or `--no-verbose` flag. From the documentation:

> ```
>    -nv
>    --no-verbose
>        Turn off verbose without being completely quiet (use -q for that), which means that error messages and basic information still get printed.
> ```